# Devexpress Treelist adding objects only show object name

Tags: c#, vb.net, devexpress

I'm trying to add objects to the treelist of devexpress. But sadly it does not fill the cells automatically, instead it displays in every cell the object name.

```
Public Class TempItem

Private m_name As String
Private m_value As String


Public Property Name() As String
    Get
        Return m_name
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_name = value
    End Set
End Property
Public Property Value() As String
    Get
        Return m_value
    End Get
    Set(value As String)
        m_value = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

```
Private Function TempItem1() As List(Of TempItem)
    Dim tmpList As New List(Of TempItem)

    tmpList.Add(New TempItem("Feature", "0"))
    tmpList.Add(New TempItem("Feature2", "1"))


    Return tmpList
End Function
```

And I'm adding the objects by this line:

```
tlEditor.Nodes.Add(TempItem1.ToArray)
```

I have two columns in my treelist. For the first column I've set the FieldName to **Name** and the second column I've set the fieldname to **Value** expecting the treelist to show the value of the properties in the TempItem class. In this case the treelist should show:

Feature | 0
Feature2 | 1

But instead it shows **WindowsApplication1.TempItem** in each cell. Like

WindowsApplication1.TempItem | WindowsApplication1.TempItem
WindowsApplication1.TempItem | WindowsApplication1.TempItem

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your list is holding new instances of the Class TempItem.  I would use an array of strings instead for this.  You can modify your class for this or just set up a list as the example below (C#):

```
    public List<string[]> tmplist = new List<string[]>();
            string[] str1 = new string[] { "test1", "1" };
            string[] str2 = new string[] { "test2", "2" };
            tmplist.Add(str1);
            tmplist.Add(str2);
```

Then create a function that takes the list and populates a `TreeNodeCollection` with the values in the list:

```
    public void CreateList(List<string[]> ars, TreeView tv)
    {
        foreach (var array in ars)
        {
            AddItems(array, 0, tv.Nodes);
        }
    }

    void AddItems(string[] array, int index, TreeNodeCollection nodes)
    {
        if (index < array.Length)
        {
            var nextNode = AddValue(array[index], nodes);
            AddItems(array, index + 1, nextNode.Nodes);
        }
    }

    TreeNode AddValue(string value, TreeNodeCollection nodes)
    {
        var index = nodes.IndexOfKey(value);
        if (index == -1)
        {
            var newNode = new TreeNode(value) { Name = value };
            nodes.Add(newNode);
            return newNode;
        }
        return nodes[index];
    }
```

Then simply call CreateList with your parameters:

```
CreateList(tmplist, treeView1);
```